# How to catch an Exception in a TDataModule.OnCreate event?

Tags: delphi, exception

I encountered the following issue in Delphi with a `try/except` block.

I have a simple application - one MainForm named `fr_MAIN` and one `TDataModule` named `DM`. `DM` is not auto-created, but it is created at run-time in `fr_MAIN`'s `Button2.OnClick` event:

```
procedure Tfr_MAIN.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    DM := TDM.Create(nil);
    Showmessage('DM started!');
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      Showmessage('DM not started!');
    end;
  end;
```

`DM` has some code in its `OnCreate` event:

```
procedure TDM.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  raise Exception.Create('this is error!');
  // DM code here ...
end;
```

The problem is that when I click on `Button2`, I receive the `'this is error!'` exception message, the rest of the `DM code here` does not run - which is correct! But then I also receive the `'DM started!'` message instead of the `'DM not started!'` message.

The exception raised by `DM` interrupts the action, but is not caught in the `except` block of the form!

Why is this?

Comment: By default, `TApplication` tells `TDataModule` to swallow an exception raised by the `TDataModule.OnCreate` event (see Tom's answer for specific details). To do what you are asking, you should override the virtual `TDataModule.Create()` constructor to raise the exception, instead of use the `TDataModule.OnCreate` event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`TDataModule`<sup>1</sup> has special handling of exceptions raised in its `OnCreate` event.

The exception is handled here:

```
procedure TDataModule.DoCreate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnCreate) then
  try
    FOnCreate(Self);
  except
    if not HandleCreateException then // <-- here
      raise;
  end;
end;

function TDataModule.HandleCreateException: Boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(ApplicationHandleException) then
  begin
    ApplicationHandleException(Self); // <-- here
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

By default, `TApplication` assigns `TApplication.HandleException()` to `ApplicationHandleException`:

```
constructor TApplication.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  ...
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...
  if not Assigned(System.Classes.ApplicationHandleException) then
    System.Classes.ApplicationHandleException := HandleException; // <-- here
  if not Assigned(System.Classes.ApplicationShowException) then
    System.Classes.ApplicationShowException := ShowException;
  ...
end;
```

So, `TDataModule.DoCreate()` is catching the exception and passing it to `TApplication.HandleException()`, which then displays a popup dialog by default.  And since `TDataModule.HandleCreateException()` then returns True, the caught exception is not re-raised.  The exception is now considered handled, allowing the program to continue normally to its `Showmessage('DM started!');` call.

To avoid the popup dialog when the exception is raised, you can assign a `TApplication.OnException` event handler:

> Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnException
>
> Use OnException to change the default behavior that occurs when an
>   exception is not handled by application code. The OnException event
>   handler is called automatically in the HandleException method.

But the exception is still going to be caught and dismissed by `TDataModule.DoCreate()`.  If you want to avoid that, so the exception propagates up the call stack, don't raise the exception from the `TDataModule.OnCreate` event at all.  Override the virtual `TDataModule.Create()` constructor and raise the exception from there instead.

<sup>1</sup>: The same thing also happens in `TCustomForm`.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr Lebeau and Mr. Brunberg!

I learned something very important this time about how things go on on a TDataModule Create event.

To cast more light on this, in a near future the DM will be created (and released) from a TService - which for me complicates things more.
I got the idea you presented, but with my skills on Delphi right now I am not dwelling into it - at least until I establish the TService - for the moment I will get by the fact of non except-ing a Raise Exception.create inside a DM.Create from another unit

thank you very much
best regards

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to fix it for all forms everywhere.

Copy `Forms.pas` from the **\Vcl\Source** folder into either your project folder (or into a common shared library folder so that all projects will benefit from it).

Then change **TCustomForm.HandleCreateExcpetion** to:

```
function TCustomForm.HandleCreateException: Boolean;
begin
{
        If an exception is raised during a form's OnCreate event, the exception is hidden.
        This leaves you with an only partially initialized form.

        The correct behavior is to **not** eat the exception.

        We do that by returning False. The caller will then throw.
}
//  Application.HandleException(Self);
//  Result := True;
    Result := False;
end;
```

If you're on earlier versions of Delphi, there is no **HandleCreateException**. You have to fix the caller directly:

```
procedure TCustomForm.DoCreate;
begin
{
        If the Form.OnCreate event throws an exception, the exception is eaten, and the caller never knows about it.

        Don't do that.
}
    if Assigned(FOnCreate) then
    begin
        //try
            FOnCreate(Self);
        //except
        //  Just let it throw. Christ you guys are dense.
            //Application.HandleException(Self);
        //end;
    end;

    if fsVisible in FFormState then
        Visible := True;
end;
```