# Exception on FormCreate is not thrown

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

By default any unhandled exception occurring in `TForm.OnCreate` will lead to an error message beeing shown instead of an exception beeing thrown.

The reason is this code in `VCL.Forms`:

```
function TCustomForm.HandleCreateException: Boolean;
begin
    Application.HandleException(Self);
    Result := True;
end;
```

All my forms inherit from TMyForm. I plan to override this function to solve the problem:

```
function TMyForm.HandleCreateException: Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;
end;
```

But I cannot imagine anybody wanting an exception on form creation to be swallowed, leaving a potentially halfly initialized form, yet this code still exists in VCL. This leaves me with the question:

Are there any reasons to not treat unhandled exceptions on form creation this way? Or are there better options to handle my problem?

**Edited** to clarify the original problem. I have the following code:

```
try
    //...
    Frm := TBooForm.Create(...);
    Frm.ShowModal;
    //...
except
    //exception in TBooForm.FormCreate not landing here.
end;
```

If I don't touch global exception handling, an unhandled exception in `TBooForm.FormCreate()` will not land in the exception block. Instead `Frm` will display in halfly initialized state, leading to hard to track errors.

Comment: All unhandled exceptions end up in Application.HandleException(). You don't show your real problem. At first glance you seem to just be confused with the debugger in the IDE grabbing exceptions before the code to handle them runs.

Comment: @Brian I edited the question to clarify the "real" problem.

Comment: @Brian The unhandled exception in `FormCreate` is catched in `TCustomForm.DoCreate` where `TCustomForm.HandleCreateException` is called. This will only lead to a call to `Application.HandleException` (=`ShowError`). An error is only raised if `HandleCreateException` returns `False`, which is never the case without overwriting it.

Comment: An aside, but I have to say, I don't really understand why anybody uses the `OnCreate` event. It's a class. If you want something to happen during instantiation, put it in a constructor. Seems like it was a mistake to have added these events at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Really? You don't unsderstand why 90% of all Delphi developpers use fomr's OnCreate event. So what do you do then yourself? Are you overriding the constructor for every form then?

Comment: @silver Yes, I put code in constructors

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043719/how-to-catch-an-exception-in-a-tdatamodule-oncreate-event/47044876

Comment: My guess is that this design was chosen to aid beginners. You may put "aid" within quotation marks, if you like.

Comment: @SilverWarior I almost always override the form's constructor. I do the same with DoShow, DoClose and many others. My form's code never use the form's event for itself. They are the free when the form is used as a normal object elsewhere in the code.